# Gerando Array Php válido para conversão jSON

Tags: php, json, array, array-associativo

Explicando um pouco do objetivo do código:
Através da consulta sql retorna dados, os únicos dados necessários são o 'id' e o nome da 'area', então é criado dois arrays, um para receber os 'id's
e o outro para receber as 'area's, depois disso os dois arrays vão ser colocados em apenas um array, o 'id' passa a ser a chave, e a 'area' passa a ser o valor respectivamente na mesma ordem. Converter o array gerado em jSON.

Este trecho não está convertendo para jSON o array do PHP: " echo json_encode($c); "

Não aparece nada na tela. Aparentemente o array não é válido para converter.
Como realizar essa conversão de modo válido?

```
            $id = 22;
            function listaAreas($conexao,$id)
            {
                $areasArray = array();
                $query = "SELECT * FROM ciencias JOIN areas on ciencias.id=areas.areaCiencia WHERE ciencias.id={$id}";
                $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);
                    while ($ciencia = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
                    {
                        array_push($areasArray, $ciencia);
                    };
                    return $areasArray;
            };


            $areasArray = listaAreas($conexao,$id);
            $arrayIds = array();
            $arrayAreas = array();
            foreach ($areasArray as $key => $value)
            {
                foreach ($value as $a => $b)
                {
                     if($a == "id")
                     {
                        array_push($arrayIds,"{$b}");
                     };

                     if($a == "area")
                     {
                        array_push($arrayAreas,"{$b}");
                     };
                };
            };

            $c = array_combine($arrayIds, $arrayAreas);
            echo json_encode($c);
```

Se der um:

```
            echo "<pre>";
            var_export($c);
            echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
            array (
              1 => 'Direito Administrativo',
              2 => 'Direito Ambiental',
              3 => 'Direito Civil',
              4 => 'Direito Constitucional',
              5 => 'Direito do Consumidor',
              6 => 'Direito do Trabalho',
              7 => 'Direito Empresarial',
              8 => 'Direito Internacional',
              9 => 'Direito Penal',
              10 => 'Direito Processual Civil',
              11 => 'Direito Processual do Trabalho',
              12 => 'Direito Processual Penal',
              13 => 'Direito Tributário',
              14 => 'Direitos Humanos',
              15 => 'Estatuto da Criança e do Adolescente',
              16 => 'Ética Profissional',
              17 => 'Filosofia do Direito',
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue seu código refatorado para simplificar os testes e eliminar os possíveis pontos de falha. Uma das possibilidades para o `json_encode` falhar é receber dados com caracteres não ASCII que não estejam em UTF-8:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$id = 22;
function listaAreas($conexao,$id)
{
    $areasArray = array();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ciencias JOIN areas on ciencias.id=areas.areaCiencia WHERE ciencias.id=".$id;
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);
    if mysqli_errno($conexao)
    {
        die( mysqli_error($conexao) );
    }
    while ($ciencia = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
    {
        //$areasArray[$ciencia['id']] = utf8_encode( $ciencia['area'] );
        $areasArray[$ciencia['id']] = $ciencia['area'];
    };
    return $areasArray;
 };

$c = listaAreas($conexao,$id);

echo 'ARRAY<br>';
print_r( $c );
echo 'JSON<br>';
print_r( json_encode( $c ) );
```

Se os dados não estão em UTF-8, ajuste a linha dentro do `while` para essa:

```
 $areasArray[$ciencia['id']] = utf8_encode( $ciencia['area'] );
```

Supondo que o DB tenha os campos `id` e `area`, este código deve funcionar com o mesmo resultado do anterior (inclusive com o encode funcionando), apesar de bem mais enxuto.

Resultado esperado:

```
{
 "1":"Direito Administrativo",
 ...
 "15":"Estatuto da Crian\u00e7a e do Adolescente",
 "16":"\u00c9tica Profissional","17":"Filosofia do Direito"
}
```

Comment: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'print_r' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in D:\wamp\www\edicao\carregaSelectCienciaArea.php on line 114

Comment: ARRAY
Array ( [1] => Direito Administrativo [2] => Direito Ambiental [3] => Direito Civil [4] => Direito Constitucional [5] => Direito do Consumidor [6] => Direito do Trabalho [7] => Direito Empresarial [8] => Direito Internacional [9] => Direito Penal [10] => Direito Processual Civil [11] => Direito Processual do Trabalho [12] => Direito Processual Penal [13] => Direito Tributário [14] => Direitos Humanos [15] => Estatuto da Criança e do Adolescente [16] => Ética Profissional [17] => Filosofia do Direito ) JSON

Comment: Eu esqueci dos ; lá no echo kkk, o bom é que sabemos que o erro aparece na tela. Só colocar os ; nos ECHO e ver o que muda, atualizei a resposta.

Comment: sim apareceu o array, eu enviei a msg a poucos minutos atrás =)

Comment: $arr = array('a' => 'á' );
echo (json_encode($arr));
{"a":"\u00e1"}

Comment: JSON
{"1":"Direito Administrativo","2":"Direito Ambiental","3":"Direito Civil","4":"Direito Constitucional","5":"Direito do Consumidor","6":"Direito do Trabalho","7":"Direito Empresarial","8":"Direito Internacional","9":"Direito Penal","10":"Direito Processual Civil","11":"Direito Processual do Trabalho","12":"Direito Processual Penal","13":"Direito Tribut\u00e1rio","14":"Direitos Humanos","15":"Estatuto da Crian\u00e7a e do Adolescente","16":"\u00c9tica Profissional","17":"Filosofia do Direito"}

Comment: O problema realmente parece ser esse da codificação. Gerou o jSON porém mudou os caracteres com acento.

Comment: @user31050 é pra mudar mesmo, é pra ficar com \0000. Pode ficar tranquilo que o decode faz certo do outro lado para converter para caracteres acentuados, acento no json é sempre codificado. Depois, se tiver um tempinho, tente endender as simplificações que eu fiz no resto do código, pode te ajudar em outras situações.

Comment: Tá ok Bacco muito obrigado pela ajuda, valeu!

Comment: @user31050 qualquer dúvida, deixe um comment. E se for sobre outras partes diferentes, pode abrir novas perguntas.